# App Scripts. I am creating an automated script to add viewers to my Google Drive folder, but I encountered an 'Exceeded maximum execution time' error

Tags: google-sheets, automation, google-drive-api

I have received an 'Exceeded maximum execution time' error.
My code:

```
function getOrderData(orderId) {
  var apiUrl = 'https://mydomainname/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/' + orderId;
  var username = 'myusername';
  var password = 'mypassword ';
  var authHeader = 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + password);
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': authHeader
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, { headers: headers });
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var orderId = data.id;
  var orderStatus = data.status;
  var orderEmail = data.billing.email
  var mainArray = [];
  mainArray.push(orderId);
  mainArray.push(orderStatus);
  mainArray.push(orderEmail);
  Logger.log(mainArray);
  return mainArray;
}
function addViewerToDriveFile(fileId, userEmail) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("myfolderID");
  if (folder != null) {
    Logger.log("Success");
  } else {
    Logger.log("None")
  }
}
function shareFolder(folderId, email) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  Logger.log(folder);
  var user = DriveApp.getUserById(email);
  folder.share(user, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  folder.setSharingWithLinkDisabled(true);
}
function setValueToCell(numberRow, message) {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var cellAddress = "D" + numberRow;
  var range = sheet.getRange(cellAddress);
  var valueToSet = message;
  range.setValue(valueToSet);
}
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedRange = e.range;
  var editedRow = editedRange.getRow();
  var editedSheet = editedRange.getSheet();SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var targetSheetName = "Sheet1";
  if (editedSheet.getName() === targetSheetName) {
    var rowRange = editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, editedSheet.getLastColumn());
    var rowData = rowRange.getValues();
    var rowValues = rowData[0];
    Logger.log(rowValues);
    mainArray = getOrderData(rowValues[2]);
    if(mainArray[0] == rowValues[2] && mainArray[2] == rowValues[1] && mainArray[1] == "completed"){
      addViewerToDriveFile("1TCtTANb46AiNUB3SYCO-lW75EXEDB1F9",mainArray[2]);
      setValueToCell(editedRow, "Added");
    }else{
      setValueToCell(editedRow, "Fail");
    }

  }
}
```

I have edited my code above, and everything seems to be fine. However, when the script reaches the line 'var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("myfolderID");', my code encounters the error 'Exceeded maximum execution time'.

There are no files contained in this folder.

i hope you can help me.

Comment: Google Apps Script can run for a maximum of 6 minutes (I believe they can run longer if you are on a Workspace plan). Where is the rest of your code, you said that you have a script to add viewers, but the code you shared just creates a folder within another folder. It's possible you have an infinite loop going that my be causing the execution error.

Comment: I have edited my code above, and everything seems to be fine. However, when the script reaches the line 'var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("myfolderID");', my code encounters the error 'Exceeded maximum execution time'.

Comment: `onEdit` (and other simple triggers) can run for a maximum of 30 seconds, so you're probably just hitting that limit (I assume the external fetch is taking some time). If you want more time, you may want to convert your simple trigger to an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) (just make sure to rename the `onEdit` method to something else.

Comment: I don't think the issue lies with the trigger because when I run the isolated command below for testing:
function printMessage() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FORLDER_ID");
}
I still encounter the same 'Exceeded maximum execution time' error, and there are no triggers involved.

Comment: I have found the issue. It seems that my Google Drive is reaching its storage limit of 6GB/15GB, and that is the reason for the error. However, I'm not sure how to resolve it.